# The type or namespace name 'Class1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using VS2012 , asp/c#

- Created New Website empty project
- created new asp file
- created new c# class file, dialog comes up saying I need to have this class in App_Code folder, I said yes ok.

  ```
  Website
    Default.aspx
      Default.aspx.cs
  App_Code
    Class1.cs
  ```

My default.aspx.cs file calls (creates instance) Class1.cs. Below error happens when I put this website in remote server. my localhost server website is coming up.

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Class1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

```
Line 11: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 12:     { 
Line 13:         Class1 cls = new Class1(); 
Line 14:         cls.getValue(); 
Line 15:     }
```

Comment: Please check the namespace of the class Class1

Comment: Add your `class1 namespace` in `Default.aspx.cs` page

Comment: how to add namespace ?

Comment: please post whole code of `Class1.cs`

Comment: `code` using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Class1
/// </summary>
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }

        public String getValue()
        {
            return "From class.. !!";
        }

    } `code`

Comment: Are you doing any special steps to deploy the site?

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DBCode' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

 

Line 6:  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
Line 7:  
Line 8:  using DBCode;
Line 9:  
Line 10: public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
 

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwCT3\dev\AssetTracker\Site.master.cs    Line: 8

Answer (score 0):

Try

Class1.Class1 cls = new Class1.Class1();

Instead of

Class1 cls = new Class1();